# VideoJS overlay and React

Tags: video.js, videojs-overlay

I was wondering, is it possible to add a react component as the content?

I added the component inside the overlay like so -

```
 this.player.overlay({
      content: <SomeReactComponent />,
      align: 'bottom-left',
      overlays: [{
        start: 'play',
        end: 'end'
      }]
    });
```

and the SomeReactComponent is just a react component for a dynamic image renderer that looks like this

```
import like from './like.png';
import love from './love.png';
import neutral from './neutral.png';

class SomeReactComponent extends Component {
  getImage(pic) {
    const image = pic;
    return image;
  }

  render() {
    const pic = [love, like, neutral];

    return (
        <div>
          { sentimentsArray.map(sentiment =>
            <img src={this.getImage(pic)} style={{ width: '75%', height: '75%', objectFit: 'scale-down' }} />
          )}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When i call this.player.overlay in my console, it says the overlays.options.content is a Symbol of React.element, however, I'm not getting anything as an overlay

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use React component for this property unfortunately, but only string or node element. Take a look to the [doc](https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-overlay#content) for more information.